# google maps in webview app must be in google maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I have an webview app. But i want to make a route description in it with navigation.

When i have an google link, i want to open the Google Maps APP. Now it's opening in the WebView.

How can i make this?

This is my app so far:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.nl");
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}



public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

 if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                 Uri.parse(url)); 
         startActivity(intent); 
 }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
     view.loadUrl(url);
 }
 return true;

    }
}

    public static void maps(Activity activity, String address) {

   try {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,         Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + address));
    activity.startActivity(intent);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.id.webView), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static void navigation(Activity activity, String address) {

try {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address));
    activity.startActivity(intent);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.id.webView), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
 }

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
   }
```

Thanx,
Marvin

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methods to start Maps or Navigation Apps :

```
public static void maps(Activity activity, String address) {

    try {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + address));
        activity.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_no_app_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public static void navigation(Activity activity, String address) {

    try {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address));
        activity.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_no_app_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have in my link:
google.navigation:q=Postkoetslaan%2012%20Rotterdam

But there is nothing opening?

Comment: If you use the google.navigation url, you can just make a query, it will computes the itinerary from your location to the query :

<a href="google.navigation:q=Rotterdam">google.navigation</a>

If you want to create an url with a starting point and a destination point, you need to use the http url like this :

<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Postkoetslaan&daddr=Rotterdam&dirflg=d">http city name</a>

But in this case, the system will ask you if you want to open this link on a web browser or on google maps app.

Comment: It does nothing. There's nothing happening when i have a button with:
google.navigation:q=Rotterdam. i've edited my startpost with the newest code.

Comment: hum.... you have edited your post, but, I don't see any calls to the method navigation() and map() in your method shouldOverrideUrlLoading() ?

Comment: How can i do that? I'm a noob with android coding ;)